# How can I recreate this wall bed with a desk?

Tags: walls, desk

I am looking to recreate this design without spending almost 5K - [image]

I found [a very similar wall bed mechanism](https://www.canadawallbeds.ca/default.asp?id=190&pagesize=1&sfield=content.id&search=99&mn=1.64.123.125) (between $340 and $750), depending what's provided, in Canada that can be shipped to me very inexpensively -

I would still would love to have the table that does't have to be folded and just turns into a shelf that slides under when the bed comes out - [see video](http://youtu.be/LAeNen6eBso). This is the ideal functionality for me, as I live by myself, have a small apartment, work online from home and when I am home, I either sleep or work on the computer - I most definitely don't use them both at the same time. :)

So any ideas how to make that table portion that slides under the bed while keeping everything on the table still there would be appreciated. If I used a drop leaf table for example, it would be a real hassle to re-setup my workstation every morning. Metal? Wood? Hinges? It does not need to support the bed, as the wall bed mechanism that I found already has a support leg.

Much appreciated, pictures of a similar design would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lee Valley -- Hiddenbed™ Bed/Desk Hardware Kit -- http://www.leevalley.com/US/hardware/page.aspx?p=72053&cat=53&ap=1 might be suitable. (And not $5K.)

Answer (score 0):

Rockler also sells plans and hardware kits for several variations on hidden beds, including one specifically intended as a desk/bed combo.

I'm sure there are many other woodworking suppliers who offer the same kits or similar ones.